# Отключить вьюшку

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть виртуальная клавиатура(моя кастомная), как мне сделать так, чтобы она была не кликабельная? пробовал `keyboardView.isEnabled` и `keyboardView.isEnabled = false` но увы, она всё равно кликается.

Comment: Может все-таки не `isEnabled`, а `setEnabled(false)`? Или `setClickable(false)`?

Comment: @post_zeew в котлине он предлагает перевести, по сути одно и то же. Попробовал допольнительно Ваш вариант `isClickable` тоже не работает. Походу надо как то проверять вьюшку в первоначальном состоянии а потом уже пробовать. Не знаю, пока не выходит

Comment: @Morozov, ваша же клавиатура, кто кроме вас знает как ее правильно отключить.

Comment: Какая разница? Это же вьюшка в первую очередь, разве нет?

Comment: методы, начинающиеся на is-  ,как правило (в нормальных API, к которым относится и Android), проверяют состояние, для изменения состояния используются методы, нечинающиеся на set-, о чем вам и сказали ранее. Что бы не предлагал котлин, методы фреймворка он не переписывает. Вы же все равно пытаетесь проверить установленное ранее состояние, вместо того, чтобы изменить его (`setEnabled()`, `setClickable()`)  или я совсем не понимаю логику этих ребят из JetBrains

Comment: @pavlofff видимо не совсем, ровно также как и я, но результат на лицо, методы с set не работают.

Comment: @pavlofff, все правильно понимаешь. У автора свой визуальный элемент, на котором явно дети игнорируют состояние родителя. Как ему не меняй, они все равно кликаются. Я так понимаю проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю `Kotlin`, но могу предположить, что вы пытаетесь применить `Enabled = false` и `Clickable = false` к макету, в котором расположены все клавиши. Учитывая, что сам макет врятли обрабатывает касания, Ваши действия становятся бесполезными.

У Вас три пути:

1) Вешать теже `Enabled = false` и `Clickable = false` на каждую кнопку клавиатуры;

2) Либо перехватывать касания на макете и не пропускать их к кнопкам `View` внутри, к сожалению не знаю, как это делается с помощью `Kotlin`, но в `Java` было бы так:

Внутри кастомного класса `KeyboardView` добавить переменную и метод:

```
private boolean mLock;    

public void setLock(boolean lock) {
    mLock = lock;
}
```

и переопределить метод dispatchTouchEvent следующим образом:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return mLock || super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

3) Неявно разместить прозрачную `View` поверх всей клавиатуры, которая будет перехватывать касания на себя.

В `Java` такую `View` лучше было бы разместить внутрь разметки кастомного класса `KeyboardView` с атрибутами `android:visibility="invisible"` + `android:id="@+id/block"` и параметрами ширины и высоты, прорисованного родителя. И добавить внутрь класса метод:

```
public void setLock(boolean lock) {
    findViewById(R.id.block).setVisibility(lock ? VISIBLE : INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Думаю третий вариант самый подходящий, сейчас попробуем, но думаю для будущих просмотров вопроса, стоит дополнить ответ(примером кода).

Comment: как можно разместить прозрачную View и т д

Comment: я не знаю особенностей Kotlin и Вашей разметки для кастомной клавиатуры, я могу написать пример на Java, Вам он поможет?)

Comment: с вьюшкой проблем нет, больше интересен участок кода "перехвата" касания на себя. + Получается я создал прозрачную вьюшку и после этого вызываю её в нужном мне методе(view.что то там?)?

Comment: обновил ответ, мб Вам поможет чем-нибудь :)